# Python: How can I change custom property for multiple objects at once?

Tags: python, scripting

I have defined a custom `EnumProperty` for objects. I want to be able to change the property for all selected objects simultaneously. I tried this:

```
def set_collider(self, context):
    selected_objs = context.selected_objects
    collider = context.active_object.ECollider
    for obj in selected_objs:
        if obj != context.active_object:
            obj.ECollider = collider

bpy.types.Object.ECollider = EnumProperty(
    items=[('NC', 'None', ''), ('BC', 'Box Collider', ''), ('SC', 'Sphere Collider', '' ), ('CC', 'Capsule Collider', '')], name="Collider", update=set_collider
)
```

but for some reason blender crashes every time I select multiple objects and change the `ECollider` property through the UI panel.
 Of course I can always right click on the property and select **Copy to Selected** but it would be more convenient if I could change the property for all selected objects at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing the `ECollider` like this: `object.ECollider` now I access it this way: `object['ECollider']` and everything works fine. Full code modification:

```
def set_collider(self, context):
    selected_objs = context.selected_objects
    collider = context.active_object['ECollider']
    for obj in selected_objs:
        if obj != context.active_object:
            obj['ECollider'] = collider

bpy.types.Object.ECollider = EnumProperty(
    items=[('NC', 'None', ''), ('BC', 'Box Collider', ''), ('SC', 'Sphere Collider', '' ), ('CC', 'Capsule Collider', '')], name="Collider", update=set_collider
)
```